# Marcar/Desmarcar Componente RadioButton em ExpandedListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter

[Em uma pergunta que fiz aqui no StackOverflow há alguns dias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100797/recyclerview-dentro-de-cardview/100868?noredirect=1#comment206124_100868) fui instruído a utilizar o componente ExpendedListView para fazer a representação de uma lista de itens dinâmica.

Após a implementação eu vi que os itens da lista foram agrupados corretamente, mas agora preciso implementar o retorno das marcações e estou com um novo problema.

O que está acontecendo é que a minha lista carrega perfeitamente, mas não consigo fazer com que os RadioButtons se comportem adequadamente, pois eles parecem não estar agrupados, então está sendo possível marcar mais de um item da lista. O código abaixo mostra como estou fazendo para carregar os itens da lista no ExpandedListView e como estou tratando o clique:

```
    final List<QuestoesRequest> questoes = questaoService.getListQuestoes(getIdAvaliacao());
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
    expListView.setAdapter(new QuestaoExpandedListAdapter(
            this, questoes));

    //Define um listener para tratar a selecção das respostas
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            boolean b = expListView.isItemChecked(childPosition);

            RadioButton answerText = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.answerText);
            answerText.setChecked(true);
            //Indica que esta resposta foi seleccionada
            int idQuestao = questoes.get(groupPosition).getIdQuestao();
            int idAlternativa = questoes.get(groupPosition)
                    .getAlternativasRequests().get(childPosition).idAlternativa;
            respostasQuestao.put(idQuestao, idAlternativa);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Apesar de conseguir mostrar visualmente a marcação do RadioButton eu não estou conseguindo desmarcá-lo, caso ocorra a escolha de uma outra opção.

Alguma sugestão? Abraços!

Answer (score 0):

Para se verificar o desmarcar automático quando ocorre a escolha de uma outra opção, é necessário que os *RadioButton* sejam agrupados dentro de um *RadioGroup*.

Neste seu caso não vejo como seja possível incluir os *RadioButton* num *RadioGroup*.

A solução passa por ser o *adapter* a ter a responsabilidade de "checar" os *RadioButton*, no método `getChildView()`, baseado em informação guardada no *model*<sup>(1)</sup>.

No `onChildClick()` do `OnChildClickListener` indique, na pergunta, qual é a resposta escolhida e faça o *refresh* da lista através  de `adapater.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Consulte a minha [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100868/2541) à pergunta que referiu para ver como se faz essa implementação.

<sup>(1)</sup><sub>A responsabilidade de reflectir o estado do *model* nas *views* deve ser sempre do *Adapter* e não apenas neste caso.</sub>