# Android recyclerView - criar campos dinamicamente

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

Como faço para criar campos de forma dinâmica em um `RecyClerView`?

Estou tentando inserir um `RadioButton` manualmente só que não consigo.
Todos os exemplos que eu encontrei, mostra que tem que primeiro criar um layout XML para poder depois criar no Adapter.
Só que como a quantidade de ítens que eu vou criar não tem quantidade certa, preciso fazer isso de forma dinâmica.

Tenho que criar um formulário onde vai apresentar perguntas e repostas. Como cada pergunta vai ter N quantidade de respostas, não tenho como criar um layout xml com uma quantidade determinada de campos, pois isso pode mudar de pergunta para pergunta.

Segue meu código para que possam entender melhor:

```
public class AdapterPergunta extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterPergunta.MyViewHolder> {
private ArrayAdapter<PerguntaPOJO> adpPergunta;
private ArrayAdapter<RespostaPOJO> adpResposta;
private List<RespostaPOJO> listResposta;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private LinearLayout lnItemAdapterPergunta;
private int mTipoPergunta;
private RecyclerViewOnClickListenerAdapterPergunta mRecyclerViewOnClickListenerAdapterPergunta;
private Context mcontext;
private RadioGroup myRadiogroup;
private RadioButton myRadiobutton;
private PerguntaPOJO perguntaPOJO;
private RespostaDAO respostaDAO;
private RespostaPOJO respostaPOJO;
private int contPergunta;
private boolean alimentou;

public AdapterPergunta(Context context, ArrayAdapter<PerguntaPOJO> adp){
    adpPergunta = adp;
    mcontext = context;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //myRadiogroup = new RadioGroup(mcontext);
    lnItemAdapterPergunta = new LinearLayout(mcontext);
    //createRadioGroup();
    //lnItemAdapterPergunta.addView(myRadiogroup);
    respostaPOJO = new RespostaPOJO();
    respostaDAO = new RespostaDAO(mcontext);
    perguntaPOJO = new PerguntaPOJO();
    contPergunta=0;
    alimentou = false;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //Chamado quando tem necessidade de criar uma nova View
    View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_adapter_pergunta_recyclerview, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return myViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //vincula os dados do DB com a View
    holder.tv_pergunta_adapter.setText("P" + String.valueOf(position) + "-" + adpPergunta.getItem(position).getDescricao());
    listResposta = respostaDAO.listaRespostaAdapter(mcontext, adpPergunta.getItem(position).getIdpergunta());
    alimentou = true;
    contPergunta = contPergunta + 1;

    Log.d("Position: ", String.valueOf(position));
    Log.d("Pergunta: ", String.valueOf(adpPergunta.getItem(position).getIdpergunta() + "-" +
            adpPergunta.getItem(position).getDescricao()));
    myRadiobutton = new RadioButton(mcontext);
    if (adpPergunta.getItem(position).getTipopergunta() == perguntaPOJO.TIPOMULTIPLAESCOLHA) {
        adpResposta = respostaDAO.preencheLista(mcontext, adpPergunta.getItem(position).getIdpergunta());
        for (int i = 0; i < adpResposta.getCount(); i++){
            if (adpPergunta.getItem(position).getIdpergunta() == adpResposta.getItem(i).getIdpergunta()) {
                respostaPOJO.setDescricao(adpResposta.getItem(i).getDescricao());
                respostaPOJO.setIdresposta(adpResposta.getItem(i).getIdresposta());

                myRadiobutton.setText(respostaPOJO.getDescricao());
                myRadiobutton.setId(respostaPOJO.getIdresposta());
                //myRadiogroup.addView(myRadiobutton);
                //createRadioButton(respostaPOJO);
                Log.d("Resposta: ", respostaPOJO.getIdresposta()+"-"+respostaPOJO.getDescricao());
            }
        }
    }


    try {
        YoYo.with(Techniques.BounceInUp)
                .duration(700)
                .playOn(holder.itemView);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    //tamanho da lista
    int count = adpPergunta.getCount();
    return count;
}


public void setRecyclerViewOnClickListenerAdapterPergunta(RecyclerViewOnClickListenerAdapterPergunta r) {
    mRecyclerViewOnClickListenerAdapterPergunta = r;
}

public void addAdpterItem(PerguntaPOJO perguntaPOJO, int position) {
    adpPergunta.add(perguntaPOJO);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView tv_pergunta_adapter;
    public RadioGroup rgItemAdapter;
    public RadioButton rbItemAdapter;
    public LinearLayout lnItemAdapterPergunta;
    //public RadioGroup radioGroup;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tv_pergunta_adapter = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_pegunta_adapter);
        lnItemAdapterPergunta = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.lnItemAdapterPergunta);

        myRadiogroup = new RadioGroup(mcontext);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams rgParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        myRadiogroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
        lnItemAdapterPergunta.addView(myRadiogroup);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mRecyclerViewOnClickListenerAdapterPergunta != null) {
            mRecyclerViewOnClickListenerAdapterPergunta.onClickListener(v, getLayoutPosition());
        }
    }
}

private void createRadioGroup() {
    try {
        myRadiogroup = new RadioGroup(mcontext);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams rgParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        myRadiogroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
        lnItemAdapterPergunta.addView(myRadiogroup, rgParam);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Erro RadioGroup: ", e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado @rubStackOverflow!

Comment: Há tempos dei uma [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100868/2541) para um problema igual onde utilizei uma `ExpandableListView` para conter as perguntas e respostas.

Comment: Ok @ramaral. realmente cheguei a ver sua resposta para esse tipo de implementação. Só que como estava tentando implementar isso no RecyclerView, continuei tentando encontrar uma forma de fazer. Mas depois que vi sua resposta, passei a pensar em um plano B, que é esse que estou iniciando agora. Obrigado pela resposta. Irei implementá-lo para meu caso. Qualquer coisa, informo aqui sobre o resultado. Abraço meu caro!

Comment: Deve haver outras modos de implementação mas este tipo de situação "encaixa que nem uma luva" na utilização de uma `ExpandableListView`: uma lista(perguntas) cujos itens são também uma lista(respostas).

Comment: Cara, foi o que aconteceu. Encaixou como um luva. Está perfeito. Ainda estou implementando todos as formas de perguntas que eu criava antes em um ListView no Expandable para ver se vai se comportar tudo certinho. Mas estou muito feliz, pois assim como o colega que vocẽ deu a solução, eu estava parado há semanas e meu tempo acabando para apresentar uma solução. Parabéns @ramaral. Muito obrigado. Irei dando o feedback dos outros modos que irei criar, mas não tem porque dar errado, pois só vou mudar de widget (EditText, RadioButton, ImageView, etc.) Muito obrigado pelo suporte.

Comment: @ramaral meu caro, consegui criar meu formulário direitinho, como disse acima. Só que agora precisei fazer algo que não conseguir. Estou precisando percorrer os filhos do meu ExpandableListView. Ao clicar nas perguntas do formulário, ele avança automaticamente para a próxima pergunta, só que tem perguta que preciso clicar, e avançar para a próxima resposta da mesma pergunta. Não conseguir pegar a posição exata das resposta, que são os filhos. Você entendeu? Pode me ajudar nisso?

Comment: Gostaria de ajudar mas não consigo perceber qual é a sua dúvida. Sugiro que crie outra pergunta, coloque lá o código relevante e tente explicar melhor o problema.

Comment: Eis minha o link de minha pergunta : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122688/obter-posi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-childview-em-expandablelistview