# Obter posição de childView em ExpandableListView

Tags: android, view

Tenho um ExpandableListView na minha app.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/myLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Crio os Grupos e Filhos dinamicamente. Até aí tudo bem.

Só que preciso, ao clicar em um filho de um determinado Grupo (`onChildClick`), avançar para o próximo filho desse mesmo grupo cliquei. Ao cliclar em um determinado filho de um grupo, ele vai avançar (scroll) para o próximo filho desse mesmo grupo que estou e não para o próximo grupo do ExpandableListView.

Como conseguir rolar o ExpandableListView para o próximo filho do grupo que estou focado?

Espero ter explicado bem minha dúvida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conseguir solucionar esse problema com o `ScrollView` mesmo.

Tenho uma Activity onde utilizo um ScrollView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tb_pergunta"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tl_principal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TableLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/sv_table"
            android:layout_height="700dp"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/myLayout"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Dentro do `LinearLayout` do `ScrollView` eu atribuo "n" Layouts criados dinamicamente. Então com isso, não tenho um layout definido para colocar dentro do `ScrollView`.

Esses Layouts dinâmicos também recebem filhos de vários tipos de widgets (`RadioButton`, `CheckBox`, `EditText`, `TextView`, etc).

Como são criados dinamicamente, eles não tem uma posição certa dentro do `LinearLayout` pai. Com isso, eu tive muita dificuldade para rolar o `ScrollView` até esses filhos.

Obter a posição dos Layouts pais foi fácil, pois só era obter pegando o childAt(indice) do `LinearLayout` principal (o que está dentro do `ScrollView`).

```
posicaoPai = lnPrincipal.getTop();
```

Mas até rolar para a posição dos filhos, eu penei.

Em fim. A forma que encontrei para rolar até os filhos foi obter a posição topo do "lnPai.getTop()" e a posição do topo dos filhos que estão dentro dele.

```
posicaoFilho = lnFilho.getTop();
```

Somei a posição do pai com a posição do filho:

```
posicaoScrol = posicaoPai + posicaoFilho;
```

E com isso obtive a posição do filho dentro do `ScrollView` que seria igual a posição Top do Layout pai com a posição Top do filho.

Após isso, é só passar para o `ScrollView` a posição do filho que foi encontrada na soma acima.

```
final int posicaoArray = arrayFilhoOpcao.get(contArray_z + 1);
myScrollLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myScrollLayout.smoothScrollTo(0, posicaoArray);
    }
});
```

O `ArrayList` eu criei para colocar todas as posições dos filhos do Layout que eu estiver navegando no momento.

Bom... espero que sirva para alguém e que se parecer bobagem para outros, muitos iniciantes como eu às vezes tem muita dificuldade de conseguir soluções para problemas que seriam simples para outros.

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez amigo.