# Varias recycle views na mesma activty

Tags: android

alguém sabe como criar varias listas (Recycleview) na mesma activty de acordo com os dados do banco de dados? Ou seja, eu tenha uma tabela chamada Categorias e outra tabela de Itens, eu queria criar uma lista para cada categoria contendo os itens daquela categoria.

Comment: Isso pode ser conseguido recorrendo a uma [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html). Veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100868/2541) para um exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver criando um aplicativo, eu não aconselharia a você colocar mais do que um `Recycleview` na tela. Tente mostrar em um `Recycleview` as categorias e assim que o usuário escolher a categoria, você mostra em outra tela o `Recycleview` contendo  s itens daquela categoria.
Tem uma forma de você pegar o item selecionado e atribuir os valores dele em outra tela. 
segue  um exemplo:

```
    Log.i("QTDE de itens", "" + lista.size());
            if(lista.size()>0) {
                ltsunidades = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ltsunidades);

                final ArrayAdapter<Tab_UC> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Tab_UC>
                        (Selecionar_Unidade.this, R.layout.list_item_text2, lista);
                ltsunidades.setAdapter(adapter);

            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        Selecionar_Unidade.this)
                        .setTitle("Erro")
                        .setMessage("Não foi possível acessar as informações!!")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                builder.create().show();
            }

            //selecionando unidade
            ltsunidades.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapter, View view, int posicao, long id) {
                    Tab_UC obj = (Tab_UC) adapter.getItemAtPosition(posicao);
                    String filial = "" + obj.getCod_UC();
nesta String filial eu atribuo o objeto selecionado  porem no meu caso apenas o Cod_UC da tabela   para você   pode ser o obj inteiro. ficaria assim:
                       String filial = "" + obj;

                    Intent it = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Empresa.class);
                    it.putExtra("Filial", filial);
                    startActivity(it);
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " " + filial, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
```

Quando você abrir a nova `Intent`, já estará salvo o objeto selecionado pelo usuário. Na próxima `activity`, recupere os dados da seguinte forma:

```
 String filial = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Filial");
```

Agora e só usar essa variável, filial (no meu caso) e setar ela na sua `Recycleview` da seguinte forma:

```
 filial.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Eu queria fazer algo parecido com a pagina inicial do Youtube onde eu percebo que cada canal é uma lista diferente, mas acho que por enquanto vou utilizar duas activtys mesmo. Muito obrigado pelo seu tempo.

Comment: De nada amigo!!