# Como usar um array bidimensional para pegar os valores dos radioButtons?

Tags: java, android, mobile

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo de perguntas no Android Studio com 10 activities. Para cada pergunta tenho apenas duas alternativas onde ficaria 1 para a alternativa escolhida e 0 para não escolhida. Eu gostaria de colocar esses valores em um array bidimensional. Como eu implementaria isso no meu código para depois fazer uma contagem dessas respostas e definir um perfil para a pessoa?

```
package com.example.bruno.limites;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Pergunta01 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RadioGroup rdgOpcoes;
    private Intent it;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pergunta01);

        rdgOpcoes = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdgOpcoes);
        it = getIntent();

    }

    public void responder (View botao){

        RadioButton rbotao = (RadioButton) findViewById(rdgOpcoes.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        String resposta = rbotao.getText().toString();

        it.setClass(this, Pergunta02.class);
        int respondidas = 0;

        if(respondidas > 0){
            respondidas++;
            Toast.makeText(this, " Questao respondida ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }

        it.putExtra("respondidas" , respondidas);
        startActivity(it);
        finish();

    }
}
```

Comment: Talvez o melhor é esquecer essas 10 *activities* e apenas ter uma lista de pergunta/respostas em uma só. Veja se esta [implementação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100868/2541) serve.

Comment: opa amigo obrigado pela ajuda, mas nao serviu eu preciso mesmo de alguma coisa basica pois nao munjo muito de android minha duvida e como eu implemeno um array  e adiciono esses valores dos radio butons pra esse array e cada pergunta que passa ele vai adicionando o resultado