# Inserindo valor do banco em ExpandableListView via hasmap

Tags: android, sqlite3

Estou com problemas para inserir valores no ExpandableListView do banco de dados SQLite Android.

Nesse meu app, eu tenho uma tabela principal chamada DISCIPLINAS e outra tabela que tem referencia por chave estrangeira a essa principal, chamada NOTAS.

No meu ExpandableListView, o *group* está sendo preenchido pela tabela DISCIPLINA do banco, que são valores já definidos em uma etapa anterior no meu aplicativo. Até ai tudo certo, o problema aparece quando eu preciso preencher os ***childrens***, esses childrens precisam ser preenchidos de acordo com a disciplina que será selecionada via *ExpandableListView*. E estou tentando fazer isso via HashMap.

Creio que meu problema esteja na lógica, mas já tentei diversas maneiras de fazer esse preenchimento, se alguém puder me ajudar ou até falar outra forma de fazer isso agradeço.

Classe ExpandableAdapter:

`public class ExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

```
private List<Disciplina> listGroup;
private HashMap<Disciplina, List<Nota>> listData;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Nota nota = new Nota();
private Disciplina disciplina = new Disciplina();
Context context;

public ExpandableAdapter(Context context, List<Disciplina> listGroup, HashMap<Disciplina, List<Nota>> listData){
    this.listGroup  = listGroup;
    this.listData = listData;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return listGroup.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    if(listData.size() == 0){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Não há notas nesta disciplina", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return listData.get(listGroup.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return listGroup.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return listData.get(listGroup.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return listGroup.get(groupPosition).getId();
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return listData.get(listGroup.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition).getId();
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolderGroup holder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_expandable_list_view, null);
        holder = new ViewHolderGroup();
        convertView.setTag(holder);

        holder.txtGroup = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtGroup);
        //holder.imbOpcoes = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imbOpcoes);
    }else{

        holder = (ViewHolderGroup) convertView.getTag();
    }

    disciplina = listGroup.get(groupPosition);
    holder.txtGroup.setText(String.valueOf(disciplina.getAbreviacao()));

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolderItem holder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_expandable_list_view, null);
        holder = new ViewHolderItem();
        convertView.setTag(holder);

        holder.txtItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
    }else{

        holder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
    }

    nota = listData.get(listGroup.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);

    holder.txtItem.setText(String.valueOf(nota.getNota()));

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

class ViewHolderGroup {

    TextView txtGroup;
}

class ViewHolderItem {

    TextView txtItem;
}`
```

Último método que tentei para fazer a inserção das notas:

```
    public void construirLista(){

    listGroup = new ArrayList<Disciplina>();
    listData = new HashMap<Disciplina, List<Nota>>();
    ArrayList<Nota> auxilirList = new ArrayList<Nota>();
    ArrayList<Nota> arrayNota = new ArrayList<Nota>();
    ArrayList<Disciplina> arrayDisciplina = new ArrayList<Disciplina>();

    nota = new Nota();
    disciplina = new Disciplina();
    repositorioDisciplina = new RepositorioDisciplina(conn);

    listGroup = repositorioDisciplina.buscaDisciplina(0);
    disciplina = listGroup.get(0);

    for(int f = 0; f < listGroup.size(); f++) {

        for(int j = 0; j < arrayNota.size(); j++){

            nota = arrayNota.get(j);

            auxilirList = repositorioNota.buscarNota(this, nota.getId_disciplina());//busca as NOTAS pelo ID da disciplina
            arrayDisciplina = repositorioDisciplina.buscaDisciplina(nota.getId_disciplina());

            disciplina = arrayDisciplina.get(0);
        }

        listGroup.add(disciplina);
        listData.put(disciplina, auxilirList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Por que, em vez de usar um HashMap, não faz a classe Disciplina ter um atributo que é uma lista de Notas? Caso queira ver um exemplo de implementação veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100868/2541), Adaptando ao seu caso Question será Disciplina e Answer será Notas.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! mas eu acho que esse exemplo não caberia no meu caso, porque a tabela notas vai ser usada em outras ocasiões, ela possui vários atributos, peso, identificação, etc. Acredito que tenha que existir uma tabela notas mesmo, não tenho certeza rsrs

Comment: As duas tabelas continuarão a ter de existir. A diferença é só na classe Disciplina.

Comment: Agora sim, funcionou perfeitamente, consegui fazer a adaptação que precisava, MUITO OBRIGADO