# Como criar getter e setter de ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, getters-setters

Estou criando um jogo de perguntas e respostas, com os atributos: pergunta, resposta correta e o `ArrayList` de opção (`private ArrayList<String> opcao = new ArrayList<String>();`). Preciso do *getter* das opções para usar na minha classe principal para imprimir as perguntas e respostas na tela, só que eu não estou sabendo como criar o *getter* de opções por ser um `ArrayList`. Já tentei de algumas formas e quando vou na classe principal não consigo acessar o *getter*.

```
public class Perguntas {

    private String pergunta;


    private ArrayList<String> opcao = new ArrayList<String>();


    private String respostaCorreta;


    //Metodo Construtor
    public Perguntas(String p, String res, String opc1, String opc2, String opc3) {
        this.pergunta = p;
        this.opcao.add(opc1);
        this.opcao.add(opc2);
        this.opcao.add(opc3);
        this.respostaCorreta = res;
    }



    //GET E SET DA PERGUNTA
    public String getPergunta() {
        return pergunta;
    }

    public void setPergunta(String p) {
        this.pergunta = p;
    }

    //GET E SET DAS OPCOES


    //GET E SET DA RESPOSTA CORRETA
    public String getRespostaCorreta() {
        return respostaCorreta;
    }

    public void setRespostaCorreta(String res) {
        this.respostaCorreta = res;
    }

}
```

Comment: Talvez ajude https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100868/2541

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O código é confuso e parece ter algumas coisas erradas até conceitualmente, daí fica até complicado fazer o certo ou mesmo responder esta pergunta.

Se a classe chama `Perguntas` deveria ter várias perguntas ali e não apenas uma. É para ser uma, certo? Então ela deveria chamar `Pergunta`.

Se a pergunta tem resposta estabelecida em múltipla escolha, porque deveria ter uma resposta como `String`, não deveria indicar qual o número do item que é a correta?

Tem certeza que precisa de *getters* e *setters* desta forma? Está fazendo porque sabe o motivo ou só porque é o que viu em alguma receita de bolo que dizia para fazer assim e nem entende a motivação disto? Sem saber porque usar algo e o que ganha com isto é melhor não usar. Principalmente *setter* que as pessoas criam sem nem pensar se o dado deveria ser alterado ou não.

Aí precisa definir como quer pegar as opções. Será retornado uma lista? Será item por item? Aí precisa de um mecanismo iterador ou ter como pegar um item específico, mas isto é [vazamento de abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101) (algo que eu acho que não vai se preocupar, mas ainda está conceitualmente errado). Vamos do jeito mais simples:

```
ArrayList<String> getOpcoes() {
   return opcoes;
}
```

Note que eu mudei o nome da variável para `opcoes` porque se é uma lista então deveria estar no plural.

E se quiser um item específico:

```
String getOpcao(int item) {
    return opcoes.get(item);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/ArrayGetSet.java).

Isto ainda é um vazamento de abstração, mesmo que menor. Para fazer sem vazamento precisaria de mais complexidade que eu acho que é melhor não envolver agora.

Answer (score 5):

Nesse caso você pode fazer dois tipos de getter: um que retorna o array inteiro e outro que retorna só um item do array.

```
//retorna o array inteiro
ArrayList<String> getOpcao() {
   return this.opcao;
}

//retorna uma opcao especifica
String getOpcao(int indice) {
    return this.opcao.get(indice);
}
```

Eu mudaria o nome da variável `opcao` para `opcoes`, porque o nome de uma lista faz mais sentido estar no plural. 
Assim, o getter da lista inteira ficaria `getOpcoes`, enquanto o getter de um item específico ficaria `getOpcao`.